# mysql query - one to many relations

Tags: mysql, database, one-to-many

I have this db:

```
chef: id,name,surname
cakes: idCake,idChef,cakeName
```

I have to do a query that print the cakes name, grouped by chef name.
How can I do with one single mysql query?

My first idea is do 2 query:

1. the first extract the chef names and id;
2. for each chef id, I do a  query that extract cakes name where `chef.id=cake.idChef`

Can I do this with one single query?

Thanks.

Comment: Show your two queries please. And sample data with the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.cakeName FROM `cakes` c LEFT JOIN `chef` ch on (ch.id=c.idChef) GROUP BY ch.name
```

Comment: Can you please improve this answer by explaining the role of `LEFT JOIN`?

Answer (score 0):

What about:
`select t2.cakeName, t1.name from chef t1, cakes t2 where t1.id = t2.idChef`